# How to differenciate 2 buttons calling the same jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 textfields and 2 buttons calling the same function.

```
<input type="text" id="value1"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" id="getvalue"/><br>

<input type="text" id="value2"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" id="getvalue"/><br>

$('#getvalue').click(function(){       
        recording one value at a time
});
```

How can I record each individual values from the same function.
Any advices would very welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommended to use the same id for multiple elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id's should be unique.

Why don't u use the code like this.

```
<input type="text" id="value1"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" class="getvalue" id="btn1" /><br>

<input type="text" id="value2"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" class="getvalue" id="btn2"/><br>

$('input.getvalue').click(function(){       
   if (this.id == "btn1") {
   }
   if (this.id == "btn2") {
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this- 
[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9CpD/46/)

And i agree with Mr.Alien

```
$('#getvalue').click(function(){       
   var value1 = $('#value1').val();
   var value2 = $('#value2').val();
   alert(value1);
   alert(value2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also as per below:

```
<input type="text" id="value1"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" data="val1" id="getvalue"/><br>

<input type="text" id="value2"/>
<input type="button" value="Get value" data="val2" id="getvalue"/><br>

$('#getvalue').click(function(){       
       var data=$(this).attr('data');
if(data=="val1")
{
alert($('#value1').val());
}
else if(data=="val2")
{
alert($('#value2').val());
}
});
```